Why does the F4 Algorithm return a Gröbner Basis?
I am currently trying to understand the F4 algorithm. I am working with the book „Ideals, Varieties and Algorithms“ from Cox et al and have problems with understanding their proof for the correctness of the algorithm.
Why do all S-polynomials reduce to zero wrt to the generated set G?
I appreciate help!

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Why don't you consult the original article ?

@JeanMarie I am still trying to figure out what Fraugère means by „the reflexive-transitive closure“ of the modulo p reduction …
